# Leaflet - Is it possible to prevent a web map from changing the zoom of the map when it is first loaded?

Tags: leaflet, arcgis

When loading a web map via ID, part of the response has an extent which leaflet then calls fitBounds which ultimately zooms the map, overriding a default zoom that is set.

Is there a way to prevent this zoom? I can override it but the map zooms in then back out again which is not desirable.

Comment: Reproducible example, please. Do read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you can change the code that uses `fitBounds`, and you would like to prevent that action from changing zoom, therefore only changing the (center) coordinates of the map view.

In that case, when you get your response, instead of having the map "fit" the response bounds, you can simply compute the bounds center and `panTo` it:

https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#map-panto

> Pans the map to a given center.

```js
const responseCenter = responseBounds.getCenter();
map.panTo(responseCenter);
```

Comment: No I'm not able to change the code. The request is made using [esri-leaflet-webmap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esri-leaflet-webmap) which once it receives the response for the web map request it calls `fitBounds` and Leaflet does the zoom. I tried using zoomstart event to reset the zoom to the default value before it does the zoom based on the extent but it doesn't seem to work and instead uses the zoom value I provided next time zoom is initiated.

Comment: Can you execute some code before?